# Error calling @first and @method together on mutation

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I need a mutation to call `Article.doSomething() : Article`

I tried:

```
type Mutation {
  doSomething(id: ID! @eq): Article!
    @find
    @method(name: "doSomething")
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Node doSomething can only have one directive of type Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Contracts\\FieldResolver but found [@find, @method].
```

What's the proper way to call a model's method in a mutation?